# MS Word VBA Macro from validation

Tags: vba, forms, validation, ms-word

I'm trying to do what, I think, ought to be the simplest of things, but I can't get it to work. i have an MS Word document with a number of legacy drop-down and text fields:

[image]

The first option in each drop-down is "Select ...", and if a user tabs out of one of the drop-downs without choosing something other than the first "Select ...", I want a `msgbox` to appear to tell them to make a selection, which works. What doesn't work, is that after the user dismisses the `msgbox`, I want the insertion point to return to the drop-down that they didn't select.

I understand that VBA has "timing issues", and from what I've read, one way to address these timing issues is to call the "return" macro from the validation macro.  So I've written two macros:

```
Sub Validate()

' Dim strBookmark As String

' strBookmark = Selection.Bookmarks(1).Name

10: If (bool_debug) Then MsgBox ("NotSelected() - 10: strBookmark = " & strBookmark)

With ActiveDocument
    If (strBookmark = "Locality") Then
        Call Salary_Step
    ElseIf (strBookmark = "Series") Then
20:     If (bool_debug) Then MsgBox ("NotSelected() - 20: .FormFields(strBookmark).Name = " _
            & .FormFields(strBookmark).Name)
        If ((Len(.FormFields(strBookmark).Result) <> 4) Or (Not IsNumeric(.FormFields(strBookmark).Result))) Then _
            MsgBox ("Please enter a 4 digit number.")
            Call GoBackToPrevious(.FormFields(strBookmark).Name)
    ElseIf (.FormFields(strBookmark).DropDown.Value = 1) Then
        MsgBox ("Please select a " & Replace(Selection.FormFields(strBookmark).Name, "_", " ") & ".")
        Call GoBackToPrevious(.FormFields(strBookmark).Name)
    End If
End With

End Sub
```

and

```
Sub GoBackToPrevious(strPreviousField)

10: If (bool_debug) Then MsgBox ("GoBacktoPrevious - 10: strPreviousField = " & strPreviousField)
    ActiveDocument.Bookmarks(strPreviousField).Range.Fields(1).Result.Select

End Sub
```

But when I tab out of *any* of the form fields, the insertion point jumps to the next form field and not back to the one that I just tabbed out of.

I know from the debug code that `GoBackToPrevious` is being passed the name of the current form field, but MS Word advances to the next field regardless.

I'd *really* appreciate it if someone can tell me how make MS Word return to and select the drop-down the user did not select appropriately instead of jumping to and selecting the next form field in the document.

Thank you.
P James Norris

EDIT:

Based on @TimothyRylatt comments, I have modified my macro and when they're called.

I have edited `Validate` as above (commenting out the `Dim` the `strBookmark` assignment, and I call it "on entry" to the *next* form field.

`strBookmark` is `Dim`ed on the module's `declaration` section:

```
Option Explicit

Const bool_debug As Boolean = True
Const str_password As String = "###" ' I have a different password

Public strBookmark As String
```

and "on exit" from the "current" form field, I attempt to store the "current" bookmark name:

```
Sub StoreBookmark()

strBookmark = Selection.Bookmarks(1).Name

10: If (bool_debug) Then MsgBox ("StoreBookmark() - 10: strBookmark = " & strBookmark)

End Sub
```

which I call from the *current* form field "on exit".

But when I tab out of the *current* form field to the *next* form field, the insertion point doesn't go back to the "current" but instead stays in the *next* form field.

Anyone have any other suggestions/insights?

Thanks,
P James Norris

Comment: From where do you call `Validate`?

Comment: Ike--I call Validate on exit from the form field the user user is currently in.

Comment: The on-exit macro is run before the tab command is executed. As it isn’t an event with a cancel command it can’t be used in this way. You would need to use an Entry macro instead.

Comment: I would use an Entry macro to put the name of the selected dropdown in a string variable. Then, in the Exit macro, send the selection back to the dropdown by using its bookmark name.

Comment: @TimothyRylatt--If I put an Entry macro on the next form field, how do I get the Bookmark name of the previous field to the macro?

Comment: You use a variable and set it in the Exit macro.

Comment: @TimothyRylatt--I didn't think Macro variables were "state" variables that would be maintained between one macro call and another.

Comment: @TimothyRylatt: And it doesn't appear that they are--I've created an "on exit" macro that stores the current form field's bookmark name in a variable ```strBookmark```, and I know that's it's working.  But when I tab into the next form field, the "on entry" macro doesn't appear to know the value of ```strBookmark```.

Comment: There are three types of variable in VBA, local - declared within a macro with keyword `Dim`, module - declared at module level with keyword `Private`, and global - declared at module level with keyword `Public`

Comment: @TimothyRylatt: I have edited my question--if you could take a look at it, I'd appreciate it

Comment: As I don't have your document, I can't test what you have done but the basic premise that you have outlined in your question works correctly. The bookmark name is set on exit and on entry the named field is validated, and the selection moved appropriately